# how to map complex type to an existent class

Tags: php, wsdl

i want to map an existent type to wsdl type

the wsdl complex type

```
 <types>
  <xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/service1/">
   <xsd:complexType name="RequestDescriptor">
    <xsd:all>
     <xsd:element name="language" type="xsd:string" default="xx"></xsd:element>
     <xsd:element name="siteAPIKey" type="xsd:string" default="xxxx"></xsd:element>
     <xsd:element name="userID" type="xsd:int" default="-1"></xsd:element>
     <xsd:element name="sessionID" type="xsd:string" default="-1"></xsd:element>
     <xsd:element name="returnDataFormat" type="xsd:string" default="XX"></xsd:element>
    </xsd:all>
   </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:schema>
 </types>
```

and i call it like

```
<wsdl:message name="getXXRequest">
  <wsdl:part name="requestDescriptor" type="xsd1:RequestDescriptor"/>
 </wsdl:message>
 <wsdl:message name="getXXResponse">
  <wsdl:part name="getXXResponse" type="xsd:anytype"/>
 </wsdl:message>
```

in the php i use this code to map complex type

```
$soapClient = new SoapClient($soapServiceURL,array("classmap"=>array("RequestDescriptor","RequestDescriptor")));
```

when i call any function i got in the server log this message

> PHP Catchable fatal error:  Argument 1 passed to xx::XXX() must be an instance of RequestDescriptor, instance of stdClass given

but it run and return the result as expected any clue how to fix this {PHP Catchable fatal error}

Answer (score 0):

Does your `RequestDescriptor` class you claim to send have any further functionality besides being a struct / variable holder? If not, drop the classmap thing and keep on throwing stdClass objects in it.

If it does something else, you'll have to track down *where* an stdClass object is passed instead of an `RequestDescriptor` instance (probably at a location you don't expect, as the request would fail AFAIK, so there are more requests handled). A backtrace from that instance could help you a lot, possibly extend your soapclient class with another having a custom `__call()` method which explicitly tests for this, does a `debug_print_backtrace()` when the error condition occurs, or just calls `parent::__call()` when all's fine.

Comment: first : RequestDescriptor is only a bean (data holder Class) ..

second : i had delegated the soapclient into a proxy class , also i checked if the args include stdClass but yet it doesn't i think the problem in wsdl file

Comment: No, the problem is not in the WSDL file. The problem is in an argument you pass. You put an anonymous / stdClass object in a functions argument while you previously claimed to only want RequestDescriptotr instances there. So, fix that (or show the code calling the client).

Comment: hay man  ... i am the one who write the code and i know what args i passed ... simple as i told u i had delegated the class in to proxy and before i call the SoapClient object i print the data and it was only an object of RequestDescriptor and the code is as the following 

function XXXX(......)
{
print_r($args); /*print array (requestDescriptor object details) not stdclass*/
return soapClient->__soapCall($functionName,$args);
}

Comment: Care to share the `print_r` argument details? Maybe you'veforgotten to wrap it in an array or something else equally trivial. Also: you may be writing the code, but you're looking for help. PHP doesn't lie: you pass an stdObject somewhere, possibly at an unexpected location, but I trust the PHP error log more then you, no offense ;)